# libcurl RTSP client implementation c programming issue

Tags: c, libcurl, rtsp, rtcp

I'm implementing a RTSP client in c programming using libcurl.

In order to properly configure the RTP/RTCP sessions I require having the transmission port of the RTSP server (to send RTCP RR to it).

I've been looking on the documentation but without success.

I guess that it might be possible. Am I right? I've been trying with the "curl_easy_getinfo" method, but I don't see the desired parameter to handle my requirement.

Maybe I require parsing whole reply from the RTSP server (getting somehow the reply string from the server that the libcurl is showing once received). But, at least, I need to know that there is no other way. And, if there is no other way, which would be the best way to get  such reply string?

Answer (score 1):

In the rtsp sample [rtsp.c](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/docs/examples/rtsp.c), the RTSP answers are parsed by the libcurl user.

To get the RTP and RTCP port you will need to parse the `Transport` header of the SETUP answer.

This could be achieve with something like :

```
int rtpport=0;
int rtcpport=0;

char *t=strstr(rtspheader, "server_port=");
if (t != NULL)
{
    if (sscanf(t, "server_port=%d-%d", &rtpport, &rtcpport) == 2)
    {
        printf("Server ports RTP:%d RTCP:%d\n",rtpport, rtcpport);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details